# Yeoman Error: Cannot find module 'escape-string-regexp'

Tags: yeoman

I'm trying to generate a app with [generator-gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) by running `yo gulp-webapp`, though when I do I get the following error:

```
Deans-Air:deangibson deang$ sudo yo gulp-webapp
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'escape-string-regexp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/chalk/index.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
Deans-Air:deangibson deang$
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue today.  I found an error `cannot run in wd %s %s` towards the top of the stack. Re running the `$ sudo npm install -g mean-cli` command with the `--unsafe-perm` flag fixed it for me.

Node: v0.12.2

NPM: 3.5.0